# WooCommerce mini cart fragments - how load script when fragments are refreshed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the mini wocommerce cart functionality on my website. When product is added to the cart the mini cart is refreshed automatically.

Code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', function($fragments) {
    ob_start();
    ?>

    <div class="mini-cart">
        <?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?>
    </div>
    
    
    <?php $fragments['div.mini-cart']  = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;

} );
```

The cart has a scrollbar script implemented that works when there are too many items in the cart.

The problem is that when the page is loaded or after adding a product to the cart, the mini cart is refreshed but the scroll script stops working. **And I have to run code scrollbar again but I don't know how.**

How can I run javascript code after each refreshing fragments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WooCommerce cart fragments allow cart related components on the page to be updated without reloading the entire page. That's done by firing an AJAX request when a cart event happens. You can reference that code by going to `assets/js/frontend/cart-fragments.js`.

The PHP code you've posted hooks in to the content returned to the AJAX request so that you can alter or add more HTML.

On the frontend, cart fragments are handled using jQuery and there are a number of events that are triggered at various stages. To run some custom JavaScript when cart fragments are refreshed, you need to listen for the `wc_fragments_refreshed` event.

Since the event is triggerred through jQuery, you need to listen for it with jQuery (you can't use plain JS).

Example:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    $( document.body ).on( 'wc_fragments_refreshed', function() {
        // JavaScript you want to run when cart fragments are refreshed...
    });
});
```